# How do to print two zero's 00 as an integer?

Tags: ruby, string

I'm working on some app academy practice questions and I can't seem to print two 00's for my time conversion. Here's what I have so far:

```
def time_conversion(minutes)
  hours = minutes/60            
  if minutes%60 < 10
    minutes = minutes%60
  elsif minutes%60 > 10
    minutes = minutes%60
  elsif minutes%60 == 0
    minutes = 00
  end        

  return "#{hours}:#{minutes}"
end

time_conversion(360)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf):

```
sprintf("%02d:%02d", hours, minutes)
```

or the equivalent [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-25)

```
"%02d:%02d" % [hours, minutes]
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple re-structuring of your code could be with one single line in your function def -

```
return "#{m/60}:#{m%60 == 0 ? '00' : m%60}"
```

Sample execution from irb -

```
2.1.5 :077 > m=100
 => 100 
2.1.5 :078 > puts "#{m/60}:#{m%60 == 0 ? '00' : m%60}"
1:40
 => nil 
2.1.5 :079 > m=120
 => 120 
2.1.5 :080 > puts "#{m/60}:#{m%60 == 0 ? '00' : m%60}"
2:00
 => nil 
2.1.5 :081 >
```

Comment: Thank you that one looks much more cleaner than what I have, I didn't even think about it like that, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

replace last statement of `time_conversion` with `return "%02d:%02d" % [ hours, minutes ]`

Check the document http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-25 for more details

Answer (score 0):

The method [Fixnum#divmod](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Fixnum.html#method-i-divmod) is useful here:

```
def time_conversion(minutes)
  "%d hours: %02d minutes" % minutes.divmod(60)
end      

time_conversion(360)
  #=> "6 hours: 00 minutes"
```